# MUI Autocomplete not displaying name after selecting option for first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm seeing a weird issue with Material UI's Autcomplete component. I have the following code at present:

```
const [isContactListInitialised, setContactListInitialised] = useState(false);
const toggleContactListInitialised = () => { setContactListInitialised(state => !state) }

const [contactList, setContactList] = useState([]);

...

const newJobStructure = {
        name: "",
        isJobStartLinked: true,
        isJobFinishLinked: true,
        outgoingDateTime: moment(),
        jobStartDateTime: moment(),
        returningDateTime: moment().add(1, "hours"),
        jobFinishDateTime: moment().add(1, "hours"),
        contactId: -1,
        jobTypeId: -1,
        deliveryLocationId: -1,

    }

const [newJob, setNewJob] = useState(newJobStructure)
const handleNewJobChange = (event) => setNewJob({...newJob, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})

...

useEffect(() => {
     if(!isContactListInitialised) { fetchAllContacts(); }
}, [])

...

return(
...
    <Autocomplete
         id="contacts-group"
         options={contactList}
         getOptionLabel={(contact) => contact.contactName || ''}
         groupBy={(contact) => contact.firstLetter}
         value={newJob.contactId}
         onChange={(event, value) => setNewJob({...newJob, contactId: value.contactId})}
         freeSolo
         sx={{ width: "100%", minWidth: 400 }}
         renderInput={(params => <TextField {...params} label="Contact Name" />)} />
...
)
```

Now, as the title explains, when the form is displayed initially, I see the TextField as expected, along with it being blank and having "Contact Name" in it. When I click it, it displays an ordered list, again, as expected.

When I then select an option, the `contact.contactName` value displays for a split second and then it disappears. However, it still *looks* populated as the label retreats to the top left corner of the box.

If I then tap the same option again, the `contact.contactName` value then displays as expected.

What on Earth could be going on here? Is it a bug with my code, or MUI's? how would I be able to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your option list is in format `{ contactId: number, contactName: string }` which is an object, and the autocomplete has been controlled with `value` property which is mapped with `number` type. To solve this issue, do the below changes in your code.

1. Add property `contactName` in `newJobStructure`

   ```js
   const newJobStructure = {
       name: "",
       isJobStartLinked: true,
       isJobFinishLinked: true,
       outgoingDateTime: moment(),
       jobStartDateTime: moment(),
       returningDateTime: moment().add(1, "hours"),
       jobFinishDateTime: moment().add(1, "hours"),
       contactId: -1,
       contactName: '', // Add contactName Property
       jobTypeId: -1,
       deliveryLocationId: -1
   };
   ```
2. Update controlled `value` and `onChange` event of autocomplete control as below

   ```
   <Autocomplete
       id="contacts-group"
       options={contactList}
       getOptionLabel={(contact) => contact.contactName || ''}
       groupBy={(contact) => contact.firstLetter}
       // value={newJob.contactId}
       value={{ contactId: newJob.contactId, contactName: newJob.contactName }} // Update controlled value
       // onChange={(event, value) => setNewJob({ ...newJob, contactId: value.contactId })}
       onChange={(event, value) => setNewJob({ ...newJob, contactId: value?.contactId ?? -1, contactName: value?.contactName ?? '' })} // Update onChange event
       isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.contactId === value.contactId }
       freeSolo
       sx={{ width: "100%", minWidth: 400 }}
       renderInput={(params => <TextField {...params} label="Contact Name" />)}
   />
   ```